# Adding custom authorization gives error : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am facing this error sometimes (not always). I create a resource and a method in an API Gateway function. Then I map it to a Lambda function. On testing it there itself, everything works fine.

Now I add a custom authorization function to the method. Now, if I test it there,

- If I do not provide the Authorization header, it works (since it is not deployed yet. After deployment, it would require the Auth header)
- If I, however, provide the Authorization token, I get the error:

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for
>   this request should have
>   been\n'POST\n/2015-03-31/functions/arn%3Aaws%3Alambda%3Aus-eas

More details: The lambda function belonging to this method was deleted. Then I re-created the function with the same name. And noticed that the method was deleted when the API was deployed. So I re-created the mapping and mapped it to the Lambda function. Since, then I am facing this issue. I am sure if I change the name of the Lambda, it might fix the issue. But I think it's a bug with AWS and not at my end. Need to clarify if there is anything I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the currently deployed version of the API is forwarding the Authorization header from the method request to the integration request (Lambda). If you are trying to fix the current state of your API, then I suggest removing the Authorization header from the method request, which will also remove it from the integration request. This should fix the Lambda signature errors.

If you're trying to use the custom authorizer on a method, you don't need to set up the Authorization header in the method request. You just need to set the authorizer identity source as 'method.request.header.Authorization'

Comment: thanks, removing the Authorizaton header in method request solved the problem

Comment: "You just need to set the authorizer identity source as 'method.request.header.Authorization'"
Can you elaborate on how to do this in API Gateway? 
When removing the authorization Header, it is passed to the AWS Lambda function correctly, but the header is gone. Is it in the Method Request ?